# 1935 Paul Heath's New Battleship Game

Tags: battleship

We recently found a game entitled "Paul Heath's New Battleship Game", 1935 buried in a box. It appears to be a resin board and the board contains rows of holes and the game includes many colored wood pegs.

I can't seem to find anything about this particular game online. Does anyone have any information about it?

Comment: Your description of the game contents is completely consistent with a similar length description of the Milton Bradley game **Battleeship**: https://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic288374.jpg or even the paper and pencil version: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Battleship_game_board.svg/220px-Battleship_game_board.svg.png

Answer (score 1):

It's a variation on the classic Battleship game, mostly played in the same way as normal.

There are possibly two versions as the patent for the game ([US2058079](https://www.google.com.au/patents/US2058079)) describes a different layout to the one that I've encountered.